# Edit a text file saved in a shared storage

Tags: android, scoped-storage

We have successfully created a text file using the below code:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                type = "text/plain"
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "logDebug.txt")
            }
            createDebugLogFileIntent.launch(intent)
```

We are getting the URI from the result as below:

```
private val createDebugLogFileIntent =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult? ->
        val uri = result?.data?.data
            val contentResolver = appContext().contentResolver
            val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            // Check for the freshest data.
            uri?.let { contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(it, takeFlags) }
    }
```

The URI is as below:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22949
```

The `uri?.path` call gives the path as below:

```
/document/22949
```

We save the `uri?.path` into a `sharedPreferences` as `debugLogFilePath` `String.`

After that, we are trying to edit the text file as below:

Java code:

```
File debugLogFile = new File(debugLogFilePath);
            String newLine = "\n\r";
            String currentDateTime = new LocalDateTime().toString();
            content =
                    newLine + " Current Local Date Time: " + currentDateTime + " Android OS: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                            + " : " + content;
            FilesKt.appendText(debugLogFile, content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

It gives us the exception:

```
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

We have tried the following solution as given on the [official site](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#edit):

```
private void alterDocument(Uri uri) {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
        fileOutputStream.write(("Overwritten at " + System.currentTimeMillis() +
                "\n").getBytes());
        // Let the document provider know you're done by closing the stream.
        fileOutputStream.close();
        pfd.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, we got the same exception.

Comment: Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT has nothing to do with scoped storage and existed already with Android 4 KitKat.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Maybe I could have said: We are looking for a solution compatible with scoped storage guidance.

Comment: And you cannot use the File class on an uri and certainly not on an unusable path of an uri.

Comment: `We are looking for a solution compatible with scoped storage guidance.` ??? It looks more to me that you just want to use an uri obtained with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. Or dont you rather not use that action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the uri obtained from ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT just open an output stream or input stream for it.

```
OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
```

Now you can write to the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As you said, I am saving the URI in the wrong way.

Comment: We need to save the Uri as: `uri?.toString()` and convert it back to the Uri using: `Uri.parse(stringUri)`.